# Is it possible for LTspice to label the polarity of a resistor?

Tags: ltspice

I know LTspice set a polarity for the resistor and by default it is (top + and bottom -)

Is there a feature which would show little + and - signs for me to keep track of the polarity after rotating them?

Comment: What is the polarity of a resistor? The polarity of the  voltage across the resistor is a function of the circuit.

Comment: You can either create your own symbol for a resistor and use that or else you can edit the standard symbol for a resistor. I also think you can hover over the two leads of a resistor to see which is 1 and which is 2. Those ideas will tell you what polarity LTspice uses for a positive current through the resistor.

Comment: I see, I can hover to get the voltage at two leads of a resistor and do a quick nodal analysis to get the direction of current flow. The polarity of the current reading from hovering the resistor is sometimes misleading.

Comment: If you rotate a resistor then hold the oscilloscope's current meter over it, the arrow indicating polarity of measurement is also rotated. Example: drop a resistor on the workarea. The label is on the right-hand side of the resistor and the current meter arrow points down. Now rotate it 180°. The label is on the left and the current meter arrow points up.

Comment: If you want things to be visible on the schematic you can always name the nodes <F4>..

Comment: One other thing you could keep track of is to know that `rotate` (`Ctrl+R`) goes clockwise. When you press `R`, the default position is up-down, so the first `Ctrl+R` will set it right-left, then down-up, then left-right. Use a diode for better viewing.

Answer (score 4):

To use the Res.asy symbol that shows the direction of current flow, you need to download the file and place it in the /lib/sym folder. You can use either of the two lib files in Spice: one is located in the program's loaded local disk and the other is in documents. You can find the top directory from the components icon on the taskbar, and the Res.asy file should be stored in that lib file.

https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=File:Res.asy